# How to create diagonal stripe patterns and checkerboard patterns?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, textures, modulation

Based on [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/27356/how-would-i-generate-these-figures/27359?noredirect=1#comment51278_27359) question, I can confirm that horizontal patterns can be imposed onto a matrix (which in this case is an image), by multiplying it with a modulation signal created with this:

```
vModulationSignal = 1 + (0.5 * cos(2 * pi * (signalFreq / numRows) * [0:(numRows - 1)].'));
```

It would also be great if someone could explain to why the above modulation signal works.

Now I want to create diagonal patterns such as :

[image]

And criss-cross (checkered) patterns such as this:

[image]

*using a similar vModulationSignal*

---

*Code Excerpt where the modulation signal is created*

```
numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);

signalFreq = floor(numRows / 1.25);

vModulationSignal = 1 + (0.5 * cos(2 * pi * (signalFreq / numRows) * [0:(numRows - 1)].'));

mOutputImage = bsxfun(@times, mInputImage, vModulationSignal);
```

*Code Excerpt where I'm trying to create the criss cross signal*

```
numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);

signalFreq1 = floor(numRows / 1.25);
signalFreq2 = floor(numCols / 1.25);

vModulationSignal1 = 1 + (0.5 * cos(2 * pi * (signalFreq / numRows) * [0:(numRows - 1)].'));

vModulationSignal2 = 1 + (0.5 * cos(2 * pi * (signalFreq / numRows) * [0:(numRows - 1)].'));

mOutputImage = bsxfun(@times, mInputImage, vModulationSignal);

figure();
imshow(mOutputImage);
```

Comment: On Stackoverflow, you need to first post some code showing that you have tried to get this working on your own. Then post what specific coding errors you have. As for the theory of why it works, you are better off asking that back on [dsp.se]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **horizontal, vertical, diagonal stripes**:

```
fx = 1 / 20; % 1 / period in x direction
fy = 1 / 20; % 1 / period in y direction
Nx = 200; % image dimension in x direction
Ny = 200; % image dimension in y direction
[xi, yi] = ndgrid(1 : Nx, 1 : Ny);
mask = sin(2 * pi * (fx * xi  + fy * yi)) > 0; % for binary mask
mask = (sin(2 * pi * (fx * xi  + fy * yi)) + 1) / 2; % for gradual [0,1] mask
imagesc(mask); % only if you want to see it
```

just choose `fx` and `fy` accordingly (set `fy=0` for horizontal stripes, `fx=0` for vertical stripes and `fx,fy` equal for diagonal stripes). Btw. the period of the stripes (in pixels) is exactly

```
period_in_pixel = 1 / sqrt(fx^2 + fy^2);
```

For **checkerboard patterns**:

```
f = 1 / 20; % 1 / period
Nx = 200;
Ny = 200;
[xi, yi] = ndgrid(1 : Nx, 1 : Ny);
mask = sin(2 * pi * f * xi) .* sin(2 * pi * f * yi) > 0; % for binary mask
mask = (sin(2 * pi * f * xi) .* sin(2 * pi * f * yi) + 1) / 2; % for more gradual mask
imagesc(mask);
```

Here the number of black and white squares per x, y direction is:

```
number_squares_x = 2 * f * Nx
number_squares_y = 2 * f * Ny
```

And if you know the size of your image and the number of squares that you want, you can use this to calculate the parameter f.

**Multiplying the mask** with the image:

Now that is easy. The mask is a logical (white = true, black = false). Now you only have to decide which part you want to keep (the white or the black part).

Multiply your image with the mask

```
masked_image = original_image .* mask;
```

to keep the white areas in the mask and

```
masked_image = original_image .* ~mask;
```

for the opposite.

Comment: wait, I'm sorry, is there a way to multiply the output with my matrix *mInputImage*?

Comment: I seemed to have been multiplying with my old workspace variables, so it was still working.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala I expanded a bit and added a section about multiplying the mask. Now I finished.

Comment: @trillian, actually I was looking for more of a transparent overlay, but that can be achieved through addition anyway - so it's all good

Comment: @SharanDuggirala If only you would have said what you wanted. Anyway I can make the mask more transparent (gradual). Please see my (now last) edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified that! When I do `mask = sin(2 * pi * f * xi) * sin(2 * pi * f * yi)` I get an `Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree`.

Comment: @SharanDuggirala And you are right and spotted an error in my code. I edited it. Please use `.*` instead of *.

Comment: haha, all done! no more edits needed! thanks for all the support!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an extension of Trilarion's answer that gives better control on stripes appearance:

```
function out = diagStripes( outSize, stripeAngle, stripeDistance, stripeThickness )
stripeAngle = wrapTo2Pi(-stripeAngle+pi/2);
if (stripeAngle == pi/2) || (stripeAngle == 3*pi/2)
    f = @(fx, fy, xi, yi) cos(2 * pi * (fy * yi)); % vertical stripes
elseif (stripeAngle == 0)||(stripeAngle == pi)
    f = @(fx, fy, xi, yi) cos(2 * pi * (fx * xi)); % horizontal stripes
else
    f = @(fx, fy, xi, yi) cos(2 * pi * (fx * xi  + fy * yi)); % diagonal stripes
end
if numel(outSize) == 1
    outSize = [outSize outSize];
end;

fx = cos(stripeAngle) / stripeDistance; % period in x direction
fy = sin(stripeAngle) / stripeDistance; % period in y direction
Nx = outSize(2); % image dimension in x direction
Ny = outSize(1); % image dimension in y direction
[yi, xi] = ndgrid((1 : Ny)-Ny/2, (1 : Nx)-Nx/2);
mask = (f(fx, fy, xi, yi)+1)/2; % for gradual [0,1] mask
out = mask < (cos(pi*stripeThickness)+1)/2; % for binary mask
end
```

`outSize` is a two or one element vector that gives the dimensions of output image in pixels, `stripeAngle` gives the slope of stripes in radians, `stripeDistance` is the distance between centers of stripes in pixels and `stripeDistance` is a float value in `[0 .. 1]` that gives the percent of coverage of (black) stripes in (white) background.

There're also answers to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35260109/how-to-generate-a-customized-checker-board-matrix-as-fast-as-possible) for generating customized checkerboard patterns.