# How to create diagonal stripes pattern of different angles and thicknesses?

Tags: image, matlab, textures

I want to create black and white diagonal stripes pattern with these parameters:

- `h`: height of the image
- `w`: width of the image
- `a`: angle between strips and the X axis
- `d`: distance between stripes
- `t`: thickness of stripes

This can be done using sinusoidal gratings like the answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424340/2093077). But it has two problems:

1. It doesn't guarantee the stripes to remain connected
2. It doesn't guarantee the thickness of stripes to remain remain equal

This is a sample:

```
diagStripes( [h h], pi/4, 20, 0.05);
diagStripes( [h h], pi/6, 20, 0.03);
```

[image: stripes]

Then I implemented another function which was inspired by [DDA line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)). At first it creates a vertical/horizontal stripes pattern, then circularly shifts its rows/columns to create the diagonal pattern:

```
function [ out ] = diagStripes( h, w, a, d, t )
% wrap a between pi/4 and -3*pi/4
a = -wrapTo2Pi(a);
if a<-7*pi/4
    a=a+2*pi;
elseif a<-3*pi/4
    a=a+pi;
end

if a>-(pi/4) % the acute angle between stripes and x axis is greater than pi/4
    dy = round(abs(d/cos(a))); % vertical distance between stripes
    ty = max(1, round(abs(t/cos(a)))); % vertical thickness of stripes
    n = ceil(h/dy); % maximum number of stripes
    out = repmat([false(ty, 1); true(dy-ty, 1)], n, w); % create horizontal stripes
    x = 1:w;
    y = round(tan(a)*x); % calculate shift amount of each column
    for ii=x
        out(:, ii) = circshift(out(:, ii), y(ii), 1);
    end
else % the acute angle between stripes and x axis is less than pi/4
    dx = round(abs(d/sin(a))); % horizontal distance between stripes
    tx = max(1, round(abs(t/sin(a)))); % horizontal thickness of stripes
    n = ceil(w/dx); % maximum number of stripes
    out = repmat([false(1, tx), true(1, dx-tx)], h, n); % create vertical stripes
    y = 1:h;
    x = round(cot(a)*y); % calculate shift amount of each row
    for ii=y
        out(ii, :) = circshift(out(ii, :), x(ii), 2);
    end
end
out = out(1:h, 1:w); % crop the result, out may have more rows or columns than desired values (n*(dx or dy))
end
```

It perfectly does what I need, but my problem is about its performance. So I posted this question to see if there is a better approach.

Comment: Have you run the profiler (function 'profile') and identify "slow lines" ?

Comment: @G.J about 75% of run time is spent in `circshift` lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the need to be graphical related only, I would stick to the first method and rely on an antialiasing technique. For example :

```
out = diagStripes(4 .* [h h], pi/6, 4*20, 0.03)
out = imresize(out, 0.25);
```

Maybe you'll have to stay in grayscale and do the binary transformation after rescaling. From your previous method :

```
binary = out < (cos(pi*0.03)+1)/2;
```